Необходимо вывести в консоль 3 последних сообщения
let thread = {
    title: "Поделитесь книжкой",
    author: "RuBrick",
    total: 23,
    messages: [
        {
            id: 13201,
            date: "2018-01-09",
            text: "Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, с одной стороны подробную, а с другой доступную для понимания книгу по javascript. Спасибо",
            author: {
              name: "RuBrick",
              login: "ru_brick",
              reputation: 3,
              role: "user"
            }
        },
        {
            id: 13208,
            date: "2018-01-12",
            text: "Неужели нет хорошей литературы?",
            author: {
              name: "RuBrick",
              login: "ru_brick",
              reputation: 3,
              role: "user"
            }
        },
        {
            id: 13209,
            date: "2018-01-12",
            text: "в общем, NodeJS это JS + некоторые доп. модули и объекты. Тебе нужна литература по самому JS и дока на официальном сайте.",
            author: {
              name: "Popov",
              login: "popov_ma",
              reputation: 2310,
              role: "user"
            }
        },
        {
            id: 13219,
            date: "2018-01-14",
            text: "В сети много сайтов с хорошими объяснениями + есть курсы.",
            author: {
              name: "Void",
              login: "void",
              reputation: 5005,
              role: "user"
            }
        },
        {
            id: 13220,
            date: "2018-01-14",
            text: "Есть большая книга «JavaScript. Подробное руководство», потом смотришь документацию.",
            author: {
              name: "noname",
              login: "noname",
              reputation: 100,
              role: "user"
            }
        },
        {
            id: 13250,
            date: "2018-01-19",
            text: "Или можно посмотреть видеокурсы на YouTube! А самое главное — практика! И этот форум — лучшая тренировочная площадка!",
            author: {
              name: "noname",
              login: "noname",
              reputation: 110,
              role: "user"
            }
        },
        {
            id: 13259,
            date: "2018-01-20",
            text: "Понял, спасибо!",
            author: {
              name: "RuBrick",
              login: "ru_brick",
              reputation: 13,
              role: "user"
            }
        }
    ]
};


Вопрос то в чём? И это больше похоже на JavaScript, а не на Java )



function printMessage(message){
    let author = message.author;
    console.log(`
${author.name}, логин - ${author.login}, репутация - ${author.reputation}

Сообщение № ${message.id}, опубликовано ${message.date}
${message.text}
`)
}
let thread = {
    title: "Поделитесь книжкой",
    author: "RuBrick",
    total: 23,
    messages: [
        {
            id: 13201,
            date: "2018-01-09",
            text: "Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, с одной стороны подробную, а с другой доступную для понимания книгу по javascript. Спасибо",
            author: {
              name: "RuBrick",
              login: "ru_brick",
              reputation: 3,
              role: "user"
            }
        },
        {
            id: 13208,
            date: "2018-01-12",
            text: "Неужели нет хорошей литературы?",
            author: {
              name: "RuBrick",
              login: "ru_brick",
              reputation: 3,
              role: "user"
            }
        },
        {
            id: 13209,
            date: "2018-01-12",
            text: "в общем, NodeJS это JS + некоторые доп. модули и объекты. Тебе нужна литература по самому JS и дока на официальном сайте.",
            author: {
              name: "Popov",
              login: "popov_ma",
              reputation: 2310,
              role: "user"
            }
        },
        {
            id: 13219,
            date: "2018-01-14",
            text: "В сети много сайтов с хорошими объяснениями + есть курсы.",
            author: {
              name: "Void",
              login: "void",
              reputation: 5005,
              role: "user"
            }
        },
        {
            id: 13220,
            date: "2018-01-14",
            text: "Есть большая книга «JavaScript. Подробное руководство», потом смотришь документацию.",
            author: {
              name: "noname",
              login: "noname",
              reputation: 100,
              role: "user"
            }
        },
        {
            id: 13250,
            date: "2018-01-19",
            text: "Или можно посмотреть видеокурсы на YouTube! А самое главное — практика! И этот форум — лучшая тренировочная площадка!",
            author: {
              name: "noname",
              login: "noname",
              reputation: 110,
              role: "user"
            }
        },
        {
            id: 13259,
            date: "2018-01-20",
            text: "Понял, спасибо!",
            author: {
              name: "RuBrick",
              login: "ru_brick",
              reputation: 13,
              role: "user"
            }
        }
    ]
}
let thread_messages = thread.messages;
let last_three = thread_messages.slice(-3);

for(let msg of last_three){
    printMessage(msg);
}




Пишем простую функцию которая выдаст нам ЛЮБОЕ кол-во последних, от конца массива, сообщений. Если последними считаются сообщения по ДАТЕ, то предварительно отсортируйте массив сообщений по полю "date".
function doPrintLastNMessages(messages, cnt ) {
    if ( $.isArray( messages ) && messages.length > 0) {
        var i = messages.length - 1
        while ( i > 0 && cnt > 0 ) {
            var msg =  messages[i];
            var author = msg.author;
            console.log('[-] Message '+ i+1) + ' / '+thread.messages.length)
            console.log(' |- id: '+msg.id);
            console.log(' |- date: "'+msg.date+'"');
            console.log(' |- text: "'+msg.text+'"');
            console.log(' |- [-] author');
            console.log(' |   |- name: "'+author.name+'"');
            console.log(' |   |- role: "'+author.role+'"');
            console.log(' |   |- login: "'+author.login+'"');
            console.log(' |   |- reputation: "'+author.reputation+'"');
            i--;
            cnt --;    
        }
    } else { console.log('No one message found'); }
}

Вызываем
doPrintLastNMessages(thread.messages, 3);

Результат
[-] Message 7 / 7
 |- id: 13259
 |- date: "2018-01-20"
 |- text: "Понял, спасибо!"
 |- [-] author
 |   |- name: "RuBrick"
 |   |- role: "user"
 |   |- login: "ru_brick"
 |   |- reputation: "13"
[-] Message 6 / 7
 |- id: 13250
 |- date: "2018-01-19"
 |- text: "Или можно посмотреть видеокурсы на YouTube! А самое главное — практика! И этот форум — лучшая тренировочная площадка!"
 |- [-] author
 |   |- name: "noname"
 |   |- role: "user"
 |   |- login: "noname"
 |   |- reputation: "110"
[-] Message 5 / 7
 |- id: 13220
 |- date: "2018-01-14"
 |- text: "Есть большая книга «JavaScript. Подробное руководство», потом смотришь документацию."
 |- [-] author
 |   |- name: "noname"
 |   |- role: "user"
 |   |- login: "noname"
 |   |- reputation: "100"


Такой бред..да ещё доп библу прикручивать....может Hello world посоветуете на фреймворке писать?

А по мне так Ваш комментарий - бред. Обгадить другого, влепить минус, много ума не нужно. Лучший способ показать другому в чем он не прав - написать свой, более правильный код.

Вместо того, чтобы быть ранимой обиженкой, надо понять, что ответ полная чушь и удалить его.

Давайте право решать является ли ответ чушью или нет предоставим автору вопроса. Что касается лично Вас - добавлю пожалуй Вас в игнор за отсутствие предметной критики.

Если давать право решать автору вопроса, то это база знаний превратиться в помойку, потому что автор вопроса не знает что есть хорошо а что есть плохо, а вы, давая абсолютно трешовый ужасный мусорный ответ, мало того что разводите помойку, так ещё и обучаете этой помойке остальных, которые, по своей наивности и неопытности будут думать, что так и надо программировать

Можете игнорировать сколько угодно, ваши ответы от этого менее мусорными и ужасными не станут

Я Вам еще раз советую - считаете ответ других мусорным, ужасным, не подобающим для приведения на данном сайте - приведите СВОЙ ответ, который будет лучше чем мой, достоен данного сайта и изучению потомками. А если такового у Вас нет - не хайте ответы других. Повторюсь - обосрать другого, много ума не нужно. Бездоказательные и огульные высказывания, да минусы ставить могу и я под Вашими ответами.

Я не обязан ничего приводить своего. Нет тут такого правила. То что вы себе его выдумали, не делает его релевантным... Как и нет правила, что я не могу указать автору ответа, что его ответ плохой.

обосрать другого, много ума не нужно. --- вы хотели написать "написать плохой ответ и считать его классным и обучающим много ума не нужно."

Вы же игнорировать хотели. Не способны держать слово? До чего же слабохарактерные обиженки без стержня нынче пошли люди
